# Importing MEF-Plugins into MVC Controllers

Tags: model-view-controller, import, service, plugins, mef

There are several examples of using MEF to plugin whole controller/view packages into a MVC application, but i didn't found one, using MEF to plugin funcional parts, used by other controllers.

For example, think of a NewsService with a simple interface like

```
interface INewsService
{
    List<NewsItem> GetAllNews();
}
```

That gets news wherever he wants, and returns them in a List of NewsItems. My page should load an exported INewsService and show the news on the page.

But there is the problem. I cant just use [Import] in the controllers, as they are just created when they are needed.

**Edit: (Importing them to the main MVCApplication class doesn't work, becouse i cant access it from the controllers.)**
I think i found a way to access the main app via HttpContext.ApplicationInstance. But the Service object in this instance is null although it was created successfully in the Application_Start() method. Any idea why?

So, how can i access the NewsService from within a controller?

Thanks in advance,
Marks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to create a MEF ControllerFactory, which will use a MEF CompositionContainer to create a controller with its imports satisfied.  Then you can just put an INewsService import on your controller.

Here is a [sample](http://blogs.msdn.com/hammett/archive/2009/04/23/mef-and-asp-net-mvc-sample.aspx) which shows how you can do this.

EDIT: Here's another [sample](http://blog.maartenballiauw.be/post/2009/04/21/ASPNET-MVC-and-the-Managed-Extensibility-Framework-(MEF).aspx) which looks a little bit simpler.

Comment: I dont like the way of adding a custom ControllerFactory, but it seems like the only good solution so far.